# How to force nginx to reload client's browser for content change?

Tags: html, nginx, html5-video, browser-cache

I have a very simple setup, but I am unable to achieve the end goal as of yet. I have an nginx installed on a VM that is serving a static html page. This html page contains the code for a video that I want to loop. I want to be able to replace the video file in the video directory and have nginx force the client's browser which is displaying the old video to reload and start playing the new file without restarting nginx or refreshing the browser manually. I should mention that the client browser is on a TV that displays the video and I do not want to manually refresh the browser on the TV and have this done automatically.

I have found few meta tags by searching around to have it work but it does not work for me. The page serves the old video and does not refresh after an hour (the value that I have specified in the meta tag).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>my video</title>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600">
<style>
    body {
        position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
    }

    #myvideo {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The video -->
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myvideo">
        <source src="videos/main.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

I upload a different video to video directory with the same name "main.mp4" and want the nginx to force the browser to reload and display the updated video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to check/keep in mind:

While `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600">` should work just fine, some (very rare ones) browsers may not support it. In that case, you might try adding Javascript-based solution, e.g.:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, 60*60*1000);
</script>
```

The `true` will ensure that while reloading the page, the browser will skip its cache and load the page from the server.

Since your page uses/links to the same video filename internally, you have to ensure that `http://example.com/videos/main.mp4` does not have positive caching headers.

You can use `curl` to check headers like so:

```
curl -IL http://example.com/videos/main.mp4
```

See what is the value for `Cache-Control` and `Expires`. You can have both, or either of those headers. For your case, they should dictate cacheability of less than one hour or none at all.

In NGINX you can set this with:

```
location = /videos/main.mp4 {
    expires -1;
}
```

Which basically tells it to send expiration in the past of 1 second behind the time when the video file was fetched (= no cache).

Comment: Thank you @Danila Vershinin. Few other questions:
1- Do I place the script in the head or body of my HTML?
2- Do I need to keep the 4 `meta` tags I already have?
3- When I ran the `curl` command, I do not see anything for `Cache-Control` and `Expires`, is this how it should be?
```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2019 16:11:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 170
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://example.com/videos/main.mp4
curl: (35) error:1400442E:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Comment: You can keep the meta tag. Javascript can be added in `<head>`. Make your `curl` request against the final (likely https://) version of the URL of the video file, which wil not result in a redirect.

Comment: When I run the `curl` against the https, I get an SSL error
"curl -IL https://example.com/videos/main.mp4
curl: (35) error:1400442E:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version"
 Also, This method that we came up with, does not require the client's browser to be refreshed manually or reloaded, correct? Once I upload and replace the **main.mp4**, it'll automatically get refreshed every 60 minutes without user intervention?

Comment: Yes, without user intervention. You seem to be having trouble figuring out the final URL of your video? The `curl` test command should return 200 status, not a redirect and not a failure. If you don't have your video linked as https:// (and neither the page), then it's not available over https and it's useless to test. And obviously, replace `example.com` with your own domain.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `Refresh` HTTP header:

```
    location = /chart.auto.png {    
        alias /run/data/chart.png;
        add_header Refresh "5; url=https://example.com/chart.auto.png";
    }
```

This headers makes the browser either to refresh this very URL or possibly go to another URL after 5 seconds.

This works for any type of content (not only HTML pages), as seen in the example.

---

While this may work fine, it is still recommended to disable caching for the object you provide:

```
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;
```

Answer (score 0):

To configure Nginx to not reload a website from the cache when a client user hits the website, **you can use the proxy_cache_bypass directive.**

```
server {
    root /var/www/public_html/react/build;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;

 location / {
        try_files $uri  /index.html;

    proxy_cache my_cache;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
    proxy_cache_revalidate on;
    proxy_cache_min_uses 3;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
    proxy_cache_valid any 0;

    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }
```